# android NFC browser integration

Tags: android, google-chrome, nfc

I have a question, if anyone of you know how would it be possible to integrate NFC with android browser (native or chrome). Idea is to communicate with NFC inside an android browser (isodep). As adobe managed to integrate flash with android browser, there should be a possibility to access NFC from browser also.

Did google allow flash through via backdoor? As I understand that it is a huge security risk for web browser to access device hardware, but I think it can be done?

Anyone of you have some knowledge to share with me?

I have written android app to communicate with NFC but now I would like to access it via browser.

Comment: "Did google allow flash through via backdoor?" -- Flash is no longer supported on Android. "As I understand that it is a huge security risk for web browser to access device hardware, but I think it can be done?" -- there are many browsers for Android. Some may offer plugin mechanisms. It is even conceivable that they offer plugin mechanisms that will work with other APKs that hold additional permissions (e.g., `NFC`). However, unless you are building your own browser, you would still need to ship an APK and/or a plugin to enable NFC capability for that browser.

Comment: I understand that it requires a plugin to make it work, but anyone have experience in writing chrome plugin to communicate with device hardware? Or creating an app to be a browser would be the easiest way out?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like the Web NFC API:
https://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/

Be aware that this project is not an official W3C Standard and is not stable:

*"Implementers need to be aware that this specification is considered unstable. Implementers who are not taking part in the discussions will find the specification changing out from under them in incompatible ways. Vendors interested in implementing this specification before it eventually reaches the Candidate Recommendation phase should subscribe to the repository on GitHub and take part in the discussions."* - w3c